# Send json to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am sending a big json file from server to jade, but the `"` are replaced with: `&quot;` therefor the json is unreadable/unparsable and I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

I send the data like this from node:

```
res.render(view, {world:{name:"SomeName",width:50},otherdata:{...}});
```

and then get it in jade like this:

```
doStuff(JSON.parse(#{data}));
```

and here it is unreadable data which looks like:

```
{world:{name:&quot;SomeName&quot;,width:50...
```

can I somehow disable the conversion of the quotes?

Comment: More details ! this question is bad..

Comment: @NetaMeta added in some more info

Comment: Why do you need to JSON.parse if the data is already an object?

Answer (score 1):

Server side within your rout you will do the following consider the object `user`

```
var user = {username:"myname"};
res.locals.user = user ;
```

response will be :

```
res.render('view');
```

jade view will have the variable available :

```
if user
    script(type='text/javascript').
        var user = !{JSON.stringify(user)};
```

Try adding `app.use(bodyParser.json());` if you still have the issue

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

No experience with jade but from the language reference (http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) i guess

```
doStuff(JSON.parse(!{data}))
```

might work